# How can I know which drivers should I download?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, asus-laptop

I have an ASUS laptop which model is `F555L` (it can be seen on the back of the laptop). I want to download the [drivers](https://www.asus.com/search/results.aspx?SearchKey=F555L) from the official page but there are three models and I do not know what I have to choose.

I also could find that my system model it is `X555LDB` (on search at `Windows10` Icon > Information System) and here I have some assumptions:

- I think that the `X` it is like a wildcard and can be an `F` or any letter.
- There are three models with an additional letter (`F555LF, F555LB and F555LN`) so I think that the drivers that I should download are the second one (`F555LB`) because the letter B it is contained on the system model.
- I cannot find out what the `D` could mean.

Should I download the drivers of the model `F555LB` or not? Can you explain me what does it mean each letter of the models?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know this feeling ... ;)

Comment: I would go with F555LB

Comment: Enter the bios, see if there is more info in there on model number.

Comment: @Moab Is it just an assumption or are you sure about that? Why?

Comment: Hey we are all guessing here, did you look in the bios?

Comment: @Moab I am trying to found it but I am not very used with the BIOS so it is very difficult to me :/ How it seems to appeared the line in which it puts it? like model?

Comment: windows 10 downloads all drivers on it's own. only install drivers if you see yellow icons in device manager

Comment: @magicandre1981 so if there is a new update it downloads the drivers again?

Comment: yes, WindowsUpdate will install the new driver updates

Comment: @magicandre1981 Although Windows does install drivers on its own, it might be beneficial to manually install them depending on the device. For instance, the drivers in Windows Updates go through testing by Microsoft before being released to make sure they're stable. This is good if you want a stable computer but can easily lead to outdated or suboptimal graphics drivers if you're trying to game.

Comment: @nijave no, for Win10, Microsoft rolls out the lastet drivers very fast

Comment: @magicandre1981 honestly the only drivers worth downloading manually are probably those for video cards--especially new ones or if you want beta/experimental drivers

Comment: @Error404 Forget the laptop model and find the device for which you need the driver.

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like What do you mean? Drivers for the headphone?

Comment: Are you looking for headphone drivers on Asus website ???

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like I am looking a driver that works for my headphone with microphone (they are both in one). And I found the link that I put before > Drivers & Tools > Windows 10 64bit > AUDIO. And I downloaded the last update (of September) but in the computer still puts an update of July, independently if I execute these drivers or not.

Comment: @Error404 That's the most important part you are missing from your question. Everyone is under an impression that you need driver for one of your peripheral device like network, video or in-built audio which isn't really the case if you are talking about 3.5mm headphones and built in speakers are working. check for sound manager or audio mixer settings. Please update your question with details about headphones

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Do you mean that people think that I am searching drivers for my computer and not for a peripheral (like my headphones with microphone are)?. Sorry I though it was a problem of my computer and it is why I tried to download the drivers of my laptop (in my other question about that problem a man told to me that it could be the problem). What kind of info do you need about my headphones?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34457/discussion-between-the-it-guy-you-dont-like-and-error404).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on Windows Update--especially in newer versions of Windows is the best way to go unless you're having problems or want to use beta/experimental drivers. The drivers available in Windows Update are the same ones that manufacturers release, but they're gone through testing to ensure they work correctly. The leading cause of blue screens are buggy drivers and going through Microsoft's testing process helps weed these out (hence the drop in bluescreens with newer versions of Windows). In addition, when you do have a blue screen (actually a bug check) your computer saves information about what happened before shutting off. When you restart, (in newer versions of Windows) there's a button that allows you to send the info to Microsoft. The information runs through an automated process that tries to identity what happens. If Microsoft gets reports from enough people they can find problems in drivers and release updates to force your computer back to a stable version.

Since they all have the beginning model number the same, it is likely they share quite a bit of the same hardware. I would probably just download drivers from each one and extract them using 7-Zip or Universal Extractor. Then update the drivers through Device Manager by selecting "Browse my computer" then using the Browse button on the next page to go to the folder with the drivers. Windows will search through the folder and look for the correct driver.

Here a second method that works especially well with older computers that the manufacturer hasn't bothered with updating the [driver page](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-find-unknown-device-drivers-by-their-vendor-device-id/).

A lot of times you can find drivers from other manufacturers or different models that are for the same hardware and get a newer driver then the one listed on the manufacturer driver page. For instance, downloading AMD drivers from their website yielded drivers 2 years newer then the ones from Dell (which hasn't seen any updates to the downloads page in 2-3 years).

Comment: I cannot find the option "Browse my computer" on my Device Manager. Where it should be?

Comment: "Update driver" (or install) > Browse my computer for driver software > Let me pick from a list of drivers on my computer > Have Disk... (you'll need to go to the folder with the inf file and select that). Graphics drivers will generally have a lot of inf files, anyone should work. You might need to extract the driver from an installer package. You can use 7-zip or universal extractor (appnee.com has a much newer repack with updated utilities than the original)

Comment: It puts that I already have the latest update of my audio drivers. But I went to the folder of the driver, extract the driver and execute the .setup file. Anything seems to change.

Comment: Make sure you're selecting the .inf file. You don't want to screen that lets you input a folder to search, you need to click the bottom option and press the "Have disk" button to find the driver. It's possible you already have the latest. In addition, changing audio drivers will likely not changing anything if the device is already working. Generally graphics drivers have the biggest impact and sometimes network drivers will help a little bit

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing <kbd>Function</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> OR <kbd>Delete</kbd> button at boot screen to access the BIOS, then go through each individual tab to locate specific hardware & bios info. if you can not find the information there,try selecting SYSTEM INFORMATION from the all apps section of the start menu (WIN 10).

You might also try installing "GOD MODE".Create a new folder wherever you want the GodMode folder to be. Right-click in Windows Explorer, select New, then click Folder. Next, rename the folder. You can name the folder anything you like as long as you add a period followed by this exact text string:

```
{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
```

This will provide you with a wealth of information about your hardware & software'